# Flexslider activate when visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I am using flexslider and I want to make a transition from the second slide to the first one when the slider becomes visible.
I was thinking about using 
if (scroll >= 500px && scroll < 600px)
for example but I am not sure how to put that into the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

You need to deal with the callback functions for the plugin you are using hide all the images from CSS by using a class let's say flexImages

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5,
    minItems: 2,
    maxItems: 4, 
    start: function(){
         $('.flexImages').show(); 
    },
  });
});
```